# Вывести дни месяц и год в таблице

Tags: php, html

Как сделать чтобы в таблице отображались:

`1 колонка                   2 колонка                и так 12 колонок`

`(Январь date("d.m.Y"))`      `Февраль date("d.m.Y")`

`01.01.2017`

`02.01.2017` и.т.д.

так я получаю массив ( день месяц год )

```
$begin = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date("Y"));
$end = mktime(0, 0, 0, 12, date("t"), date("Y"));
  $days = array();
for($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i += 86400)
{
$days[] =  date("d.m.Y", $i);
}
```

А в таблицу не получается вставить что бы месяца отображались в колонках, что бы новый месяц отображался в следуюшей колонке

`<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($days as $day) {  ?>
        <td><?php echo $day?></td>
        <?php } ?>
    </tr>
</table>`

Так получается все в одной колонке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// начинаем с 1-го января
$start = strtotime(date("Y") . '-1-1');
$month = [];
for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
  // Узнаем число дней в месяце
  $dayInMonth =  date("t", $start);
  // Заполняем массив днями
  $month[$i] = range(1,  $dayInMonth);
  // а в хвост до 31 дописываем &nbsp;
  $month[$i] += array_fill($dayInMonth, 31-$dayInMonth, '&nbsp;');
  // первое число следующего месяца
  $start = strtotime('next month', $start);
}
```

Надеюсь, что цикл вывода таблицы из 12 массивов одинаковой длины вы самостоятельно напишите